# Login identity when system sleeps

Tags: password-recovery, rescue-mode

System went to sleep, then asked for a password.  I have tried every password I have ever used.  Does ubuntu require something different.  I loaded this two years ago, last summer.  I do not remember, how do I get it back?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you be more specific about "System went to sleep"? Did you use the suspend-to-RAM (standby) feature and is it asking for a password in the screenlock? Or do you mean you haven't used this machine for two years and you need password recovery?

Answer (score 0):

I would boot from a System Rescue CD (http://www.sysresccd.org) and mount your filesystem, chroot into it and then change the password.

This is done like so:

1. Either run `fdisk -l` or `blkid` to identify which disk and partition is your root filesystem. I will assume it is `/dev/sda5`.
2. Mount it with `mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`. Sometimes it might be necessary to specify which filesystem is used, for example `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /mnt`.
3. Then chroot into it, `chroot /mnt`. This is done so that the commands that follow is issued from within the filesystem root of your on-disk installation.
4. Change the password with `passwd chastain` or any other user.

Note that there are many ways in which this procedure can go wrong. Refer to the excellent documentation at http://www.sysresccd.org/Online-Manual-EN for how to handle LVM, etc.